# CrashLoopBackOff - Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I have my image hosted on GCR.
I want to create Kubernetes Cluster on my local system(mac).

Steps I followed :

1. Create a imagePullSecretKey
2. Create generic key to communicate with GCP. (kubectl create secret generic gcp-key --from-file=key.json)
3. I have deployment.yaml file

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: sv-premier
> spec:
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: sv-premier
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: sv-premier
>     spec:
>       volumes:
>       - name: google-cloud-key
>         secret:
>           secretName: gcp-key
>       containers:
>       - name: sv-premier
>         image: gcr.io/proto/premiercore1:latest
>         imagePullPolicy: Always
>         command: ["echo", "Done deploying sv-premier"]
>         volumeMounts:
>         - name: google-cloud-key
>           mountPath: /var/secrets/google
>         env:
>         - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
>           value: /var/secrets/google/key.json
>         ports:
>         - containerPort: 8080
>       imagePullSecrets:
>       - name: imagepullsecretkey
> ```

When I execute the command - kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml , I get **CrashLoopBackOff** Error

Logs for -

> kubectl describe pods podname

=======================

> Name:           sv-premier-6b77ddd747-cvdr5
>
> Namespace:      default
>
> Priority:       0
>
> Node:           docker-desktop/192.168.65.3
>
> Start Time:     Tue, 04 Feb 2020 14:18:47 +0530
>
> Labels:         app=sv-premier
>
> pod-template-hash=6b77ddd747
>
> Annotations:
>
> Status:         Running
>
> IP:             10.1.0.43
>
> IPs:
>
> Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/sv-premier-6b77ddd747
>
> Containers:
>
> sv-premierleague:
>
> ```
> Container ID:  docker://141126d732409427fe39b405865f88856ac4e1d8586112797fc5bf4fdfbe317c
>
> Image:         gcr.io/proto/premiercore1:latest
>
> Image ID:      docker-pullable://gcr.io/proto/premiercore1@sha256:b3800ccca3f30725d5c9235dd349548f0fcfe309f51883d8af16397aef2c3953
>
> Port:          8080/TCP
>
> Host Port:     0/TCP
>
> Command:
>
>   echo
>
>   Done deploying sv-premier
>
> State:          Waiting
>
>   Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
>
> Last State:     Terminated
>
>   Reason:       Completed
>
>   Exit Code:    0
>
>   Started:      Tue, 04 Feb 2020 15:00:51 +0530
>
>   Finished:     Tue, 04 Feb 2020 15:00:51 +0530
>
> Ready:          False
>
> Restart Count:  13
>
> Environment:
>
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:  /var/secrets/google/key.json
>
> Mounts:
>
>   /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-s4jgd (ro)
>
>   /var/secrets/google from google-cloud-key (rw)
> ```
>
> Conditions:
>
> Type              Status
>
> Initialized       True
>
> Ready             False
>
> ContainersReady   False
>
> PodScheduled      True
>
> Volumes:
>
> google-cloud-key:
>
> ```
> Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
>
> SecretName:  gcp-key
>
> Optional:    false
> ```
>
> default-token-s4jgd:
>
> ```
> Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
>
> SecretName:  default-token-s4jgd
>
> Optional:    false
> ```
>
> QoS Class:       BestEffort
>
> Node-Selectors:
>
> Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
>
> ```
>              node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
> ```
>
> Events:
>
> Type     Reason     Age                  From
>   Message
>
> ### ----     ------     ----                 ----
>
> Normal   Scheduled  46m                  default-scheduler
>   Successfully assigned default/sv-premier-6b77ddd747-cvdr5 to
>   docker-desktop
>
> Normal   Pulled     45m (x4 over 46m)    kubelet, docker-desktop 
>   Successfully pulled image
>   "gcr.io/proto/premiercore1:latest"
>
> Normal   Created    45m (x4 over 46m)    kubelet, docker-desktop 
>   Created container sv-premier
>
> Normal   Started    45m (x4 over 46m)    kubelet, docker-desktop 
>   Started container sv-premier
>
> Normal   Pulling    45m (x5 over 46m)    kubelet, docker-desktop 
>   Pulling image "gcr.io/proto/premiercore1:latest"
>
> Warning  BackOff    92s (x207 over 46m)  kubelet, docker-desktop 
>   Back-off restarting failed container

=======================

And output for -

> kubectl logs podname --> *Done Deploying sv-premier*

I am confused why my container is exiting. not able to start.

Kindly guide please.

Comment: Your container has completed with exit code zero , which is success code. You should replace your command by a long running command like `sleep`

Comment: Thanks DT. It solved my problem. One quick question here - As deployment is created, I am trying to access the application using curl http://localhost:8080 but -- Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: You will need to expose your deployment via service read more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Comment: Hi @DT. can u please look at this once -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/60088378/2784032

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your deployment.yaml with a long running task example.

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "while true; do echo Done Deploying sv-premier; sleep 3600;done"]
```

This will put your container to sleep after deployment and every hour it will log the message.

Read more about [pod lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) container states [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states)